# Need advise on iterating through a Java List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, json, java-8, iteration

I need advice on how to best iterate through a `List<Map<String, String>>` object for the following outcome:

The object holds data which was fetched from a sql database. Each Map entry describes a single column of the returned data:

```
0 =
    0 =
      key = "ColumnA"
      value = "1"
    1 =
      key = "ColumnB"
      value = "2"
    2 =
      key = "ColumnC"
      value = "3"
1 =
    0 =
      key = "ColumnA"
      value = "1"
    1 =
      key = "ColumnB"
      value = "2"
    2 =
      key = "ColumnC"
      value = "3"
```

An actual data example would look as follows:

```
0 =
    0 =
      key = "Itemtype"
      value = "1"
    1 =
      key = "Itemdate"
      value = "01.01.2018"
    2 =
      key = "Subitem"
      value = "A"
    3 =
      key = "Subitemdetail"
      value = "A"
    4 =
      key = "Subitemdetail2"
      value = "A"
1 =
    0 =
      key = "Itemtype"
      value = "1"
    1 =
      key = "Itemdate"
      value = "01.01.2018"
    2 =
      key = "Subitem"
      value = "B"
    3 =
      key = "Subitemdetail"
      value = "B"
    4 =
      key = "Subitemdetail2"
      value = "B"
2 =
    0 =
      key = "Itemtype"
      value = "2"
    1 =
      key = "Itemdate"
      value = "01.01.2018"
    2 =
      key = "Subitem"
      value = "A"
    3 =
      key = "Subitemdetail"
      value = "A"
    4 =
      key = "Subitemdetail2"
      value = "A"
3 =
    0 =
      key = "Itemtype"
      value = "2"
    1 =
      key = "Itemdate"
      value = "01.01.2018"
    2 =
      key = "Subitem"
      value = "B"
    3 =
      key = "Subitemdetail"
      value = "B"
    4 =
      key = "Subitemdetail2"
      value = "B"
```

Currently, the data is returned in similar format as a JSON, via the snippet:

```
  JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();   

  for (Map<String, String> res : data) {
      JSONObject resObject = new JSONObject();

      for (Entry<String, String> subres : res.entrySet()) {
         resObject.put(subres.getKey(), subres.getValue());
      }

     resultSet.put(resObject);
  }
```

The snippet above returns the following JSON:

```
{
"res":[
    {
        "Itemtype": "1",
        "Itemdate": "01.01.2018",
        "Subitem": "A",
        "Subitemdetail": "A",
        "Subitemdetail2": "A"
    },
    {
        "Itemtype": "1",
        "Itemdate": "01.01.2018",
        "Subitem": "B",
        "Subitemdetail": "B",
        "Subitemdetail2": "B"
    },
    {
        "Itemtype": "2",
        "Itemdate": "01.01.2018",
        "Subitem": "A",
        "Subitemdetail": "A",
        "Subitemdetail2": "A"
    },
    {
        "Itemtype": "2",
        "Itemdate": "01.01.2018",
        "Subitem": "B",
        "Subitemdetail": "B",
        "Subitemdetail2": "B"
    }
]}
```

**Desired outcome:**

However, I now want to group the JSON based on the Itemtype value. The desired outcome is as follows:

```
{
"result":[
{
    "Itemtype": "1",
    "Itemdate": "01.01.2018",
    "Subitem": [
        {
            "Subitem": "A",
            "Subitemdetail": "A",
            "Subitemdetail2": "A"
        },
        {
            "Subitem": "B",
            "Subitemdetail": "B",
            "Subitemdetail2": "B"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Itemtype": "2",
    "Itemdate": "01.01.2018",
    "Subitem": [
        {
            "Subitem": "A",
            "Subitemdetail": "A",
            "Subitemdetail2": "A"
        },
        {
            "Subitem": "B",
            "Subitemdetail": "B",
            "Subitemdetail2": "B"
        }
    ]
}
]}
```

I am trying to think of a way on how to best iterate through the `List<Map<String, String>>` object. Could you perhaps give me an advise?

Because I could currently only think of very ugly solutions, for instance to first go through the object as a whole and store a list of itemtypes with their positions, means for the example above:
Item 1: 0, 1 and Item 2: 1, 2.
I would then go through the list and build myself the JSON. But perhaps you could give me an advise for a better approach? Or maybe is there even a Java 8 stream which would solve the issue better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're pulling the data wrong. Is the result you get from the web server or wherever you're pulling it from, in the proper JSON format? I can definitely help you I just need more information. Post the data result you get from the server.

Comment: If you are going to do some business logic on the data at some point you are better-off putting the data in a class. Otherwise it gets messy (as you can see) and you are not really programming in Java.

Comment: I can post the data result in a couple of hours. How would you pull the data differently though? Regarding puttin the data in a class: I was thinking the same but nothing else is done with the data currently anyway so for now it would just be an additional step, and I would still need a way to iterate through it anyhow:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the groupingBy stream collector to get a Map and then transform each entry into the final structure you want via reduce

Something like

```
// Group into Itemtype -> objects Map
Map<String, List<JSONObject>> grouped = results.stream().collect(groupingBy(obj -> obj.getString("Itemtype"))

// Reduce entries into single JSON array where the Itemtype is a top level property and the entries are under Subitem
grouped.entries().stream().reduce(result, entry-> {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.putString("Itemtype", entry.getKey());
    obj.putObject("Subitem", entry.getValue());

    result.put(obj);
    return result;
}, new JSONArray())
```

This doesnt do what you want perfectly with the properties but I believe you can figure out the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm looking into groupingBy as we speak and it's a step forward. I can't get your snippet work though, first issue I face is the following: groupingBy(obj -> obj.getString("Itemtype") - this won't work unless I work with grouped object being a Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> instead of Map<String, List<JSONObject>>.

Comment: This was an example that was written without actual testing to show how it could be done. You are expected to take it to completion.